# How do I get large images in my tumblr custom theme?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

In Tumblr, [the maximum image size is 500px](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photo-posts). I want to know how to get larger images in my custom theme.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only complexity is including a fallback so that if no high resolution image exists, the standard size one is used. **Note:** these instructions are for custom theme creation, using Tumblr's theming language. It's also worth noting that this must be within a photo block `{block:Photo} {/block:Photo}`

This method hinges on Tumblr's `{block:HighRes}`. Code wrapped with `{block:HighRes}{/block:HighRes}` only exists if a high resolution version of the image is present.

*First*, hide the normal image.

```
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" {block:HighRes}style="display:none"{/block:HighRes} />
```

*Second*, display the large image with a custom class.

```
{block:HighRes}
    <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="highres">
{/block:HighRes}
```

**Note:** The class is necessary as you will likely need to set a maximum image width. If you don't want to mess around with custom CSS you can generally just use `style="max-width:100%"` within the img tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use {PhotoURL-HighRes} - it also comes with a block to detect whether there is a Hi res photo uploaded or not. [Docs and details can be found here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photo-posts) : )

Also, it's likely that you will want to differentiate between when you have uploaded a hi-res photo and not. Using blocks like this, you can have tumblr display a hi-res picture if available, and if not default to the 500px version.

```
{block:IfContentWidth500}
    <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
{/block:IfContentWidth500}

{block:IfNotContentWidth500}
    <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
{/block:IfNotContentWidth500}
```

Note that high res photos will render at the size they were uploaded. In order to keep them behaving, it helps to add a `max-width` property to your image element or container in your styles.

Also, you need to [enable hi-res photos from your theme options](http://staff.tumblr.com/post/83565864/high-res-photos)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, asked this to answer myself, didn't realise I have to wait 7 hours... :S

Comment: It says you added this less than a half hour ago... but your welcome!

Comment: I meant to answer it myself ;)

Comment: Certainly. I was trying to be a semantic internet citizen and answer this question on quora by linking here.

Comment: Blocks `{block:IfNotContentWidth500}` and `{block:IfContentWidth500}` not working for me. Where can be the error?